# C# ListBox OwnerDrawFixedMode scrolling doesnt show list properly

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, smooth-scrolling

I am using a listbox item in C# (windows 64bit) and I wanted to color different items with different
colors. 
I managed doing so by setting the listbox to OwnerDrawFixed and "overloading" the DrawItem function

```
  this.TestList.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
  this.TestList.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.TestList_DrawItem);
    private void TestList_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        TestListItem item = TestList.Items[e.Index] as TestListItem; 
        bool selected = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected);
        if (item != null)
        {
            SolidBrush backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrushSelected;
            if (selected)
            {
                backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrushSelected;
            }
            SolidBrush foregroundBrush = (selected) ? reportsForegroundBrushSelected : reportsForegroundBrush;
            e.Graphics.DrawString( // Draw the appropriate text in the ListBox
                item.GetTestName(), // The message linked to the item
                TestList.Font, // Take the font from the listbox
                new SolidBrush(item.GetColor()), // Set the color 
                0, // X pixel coordinate
                e.Index * TestList.ItemHeight // Y pixel coordinate.  Multiply the index by the ItemHeight defined in the listbox.
            );
            //background:
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

Selecting an item works properly as well.
However, when trying to scroll the list items are "blinking" - sometimes disappear until I click
them and force the draw item again.
My theory is that I need to overload the scroller event and call a refresh function, perhaps?

I'd appreciate any help,

Thanks,
Despairy

Images:
 http://i62.tinypic.com/25soga1.jpg

http://i57.tinypic.com/2di20er.jpg

EDIT: 
Looks like e.bounds was the solution.

scrolling and dragging the mouse probably edited the Y property. proper call:

```
  e.Graphics.DrawString( // Draw the appropriate text in the ListBox
                item.GetTestName(), // The message linked to the item
                TestList.Font, // Take the font from the listbox
                new SolidBrush(item.GetColor()), // Set the color 
                e.Bounds.X, // X pixel coordinate
                e.Bounds.Y // Y pixel coordinate.  Multiply the index by the ItemHeight defined in the listbox.
            );
```

Comment: are you familiar with the `ListBox.BeginUpdate();` and `ListBox.EndUpdate();` methods.. this sounds like that could be something to look into to stop the flickering

Comment: a) that doesnt look like an overload to me b) you could/should use `TextRenderer` instead of `graphics.DrawString()` c) you dont need to calc X and Y, `e.Bounds` already has the location d) the images look like there is a horizontal offset problem

Comment: I have tried adding the being/end update where I populate the list.
It didn't help.
I'm not sure about the horizontal offset problem since when I scroll the items are not visible anymore until I click them (a call to draw item is made?)

Comment: this is the "overload" i was talking about:
    
            this.TestList.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            this.TestList.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.TestList_DrawItem);

Comment: try getting your X,Y from `e.Bounds` there is no reason not to use what the event provides.

Comment: e.Bounds was the solution.

Comment: why do you set back/foreground brushes if you dont use them?

Comment: Tried to remove as many unnecessary lines of code in order to focus on the issue :) , thanks